# Django Attribute error:'function' object has no attribute '__self__'

Tags: python, django

Django Attribute error:'function' object has no attribute '**self**'

This is my model.py file and I am getting following error:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
import uuid


from rgbfield.fields import RGBColorField

class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    index = models.IntegerField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
    theme_color = RGBColorField(default="#fff")
    text_color = RGBColorField(default="#000")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Tool(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, db_index=True, max_length=100, help_text="The name of your tool (must be unique)")
    byline = models.CharField(max_length=100,help_text="The byline of your tool (can contain HTML)")
    description = models.TextField(help_text="A description of your tool (can contain HTML)")
    logo_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image', blank=True, help_text="Use to upload an (optional) logo image for your tool")
    logo_link = models.URLField(blank=True, help_text="An (optional) link to be associated with your tool's logo")
    about_link = models.URLField(blank=True, help_text="An (optional) link to further information about your tool")
    install_link = models.URLField(blank=True, help_text="An (optional) link to local installation information for your tool")
    launch_link = models.URLField(blank=True, help_text="An (optional) link to launch your tool. If hosted by EMAC, leave this blank.")
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name="tools")
    is_external = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def tool_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # Image file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/tools/<id>/<filename>
        return "tools/{0}/{1}".format(instance.id, filename)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have checked everything but don't know what's causing this error. Any insights to what is causing the error would be very helpful.

This is view.py file

```html
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Category, Tool

# Create your views here.
def homepage(request):

    category = Category.objects.all()
    tool = Tool.objects.all()

    context = {
        'Tool': tool,
        'Category': category,
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html',context)
```

Comment: Your indentation is wonky. Please also include the traceback.

Comment: I have a feeling that the edit to indentation might be masking this issue?

Comment: that is not with your models that we will identify your issue, you should show which view/other files related causes that. You models are well-structured

Comment: where do you use this method `tool_directory_path(instance, filename)` ?

Comment: what were you doing where the bug has occurred? run command in the console? load the project? be specific

Comment: @Lemayzeur, I received this error when I was creating db.